# State machines with temporal events

Tags: state-machine

I have defined a finite state machine

```
Q = {Σ, S, s0, δ, F}

where 

Σ = {'[r]equest', '[o]ut', '[i]n', '[e]nd'}

S = {'[R]eady', '[I]nitiating', '[W]aiting', 'Re[C]eived', 'Re[S]etting'}

s0 = R,

F = {R}

δ =  (q ∈ S and x ∈ Σ)

 q      x      q
-------------------
 R      r      I
 I      o      W
 W      i      C
 C      e      S
 S      ∈      R
```

However, I have a transition from  W to S via a temporal event, i.e., the transition should happen after a stipulated amount of time. How could I handle it?

Comment: Does this fit better on cstheory.SE? http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Voting to move to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Mchl: I think it's a better fit for CS.SE. Programmers.SE is for people more into practical software development.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where the problem is.  You are allowed to define more than one transition from any given state (distinguished by input).

Comment: Thank you CodeInChaos, I will try in cstheory.SE!

Comment: The headless closing monster attacks again! Since when FSMs are beyond SO scope? Are we only going to deal with syntax issues?

Comment: @Oli, my problem is the event is temporal, which means, it is technically not a part of Σ

Comment: BoltClock, CodeInChaos: Agree on cstheory. We don't have this migration in `close` window however, so I voted on programmers.

Comment: @CMR: I don't know what you mean by "temporal" in this context.  Could you clarify?

Comment: I have no clue about the mathematical representation of statemachines, but I'd model the passing time as a kind of input.

Comment: Sorry, my vocabulary might be wrong... Edited the question.

Comment: @CMR: I agree with @ChodeInChaos's suggestion.  Model the timeout as an input event.

Comment: @Oli, CodeInChaos: I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution. For eg., in a programming world, there are shortcuts: Each instance of FSM in W initializes another co-routine (e.g.: EJB timeout/quartz) to call back after timeout. Or, creating a system that constantly sends messages at specific intervals for all FSM instances...

Comment: @CMR: Indeed, that's what would happen in the real world!  But an FSM (in this context) is just a mathematical model describing how a particular black box responds to events.  Outside the black box, you're free to do what you like (including firing off threads in response to state changes, which in turn cause input events), but this won't affect the description of the black box, i.e. the relationship between transitions.

Comment: @Oli, unfortunately, the FSM is not complete without an external system.

Comment: @CMR: Yes it is!  A FSM is not intended (necessarily) to represent the entire system; it's just one component.

Comment: I assume that you just need a description of the interaction of the external system with the statemachine and not a description of the external system itself. Else the external system wouldn't be external anymore.